# Why mixture model with Gibbs sampling works?

Tags: machine-learning, nonparametric, unsupervised-learning, gaussian-mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I just have a question about why Gibbs sampling can correctly estimate parameters with random initial value?
That is to say,we can sample z by:
\begin{align}
    p(z_i=k \,|\, \cdot) 
        &\propto
           \prod_i^n
           \prod_k^K
           \left(
               \pi_k 
               \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}
        \text{exp}\left\{
            \frac{-(x_i-\theta_k)^2}{2\sigma^2}
         \right\}
           \right)^{\delta(z_i, k)} \\
        &\propto
            \pi_k \cdot
            \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} 
            \text{exp}\left\{
                \frac{-(x_i-\theta_k)^2}{2\sigma^2}
             \right\}
\end{align}
Then update parameters
After several iteration of these two-step, it gets true distribution with random initialization. Why it converges to the true distribution? I don't understand.
Which information contribute to the change of parameters to the true value?